# Reorganise Data in r

Tags: r, sorting

I have a table for example:

```
House,Name1,Email1@xyz.com
Flat,Name2;Name3,Email2@xyz.com;Email3@xyz.com
Mobile Home,Name4,Email4@xyz.com
Camper-Van,Name5;Name6;Name7;Name8,Email5@xyz.com;Email6@xyz.com;Email7@xyz.com;Email8@xyz.com
```

and I need:

```
House,Name1,Email1@xyz.com
Flat,Name2,Email2@xyz.com
Flat,Name3,Email3@xyz.com
Mobile Home,Name4,Email4@xyz.com
Camper-Van,Name5,Emil5@xyz.com
Camper-Van,Name6,Email6@xyz.com
Camper-Van,Name7,Email7@xyz.com
Camper-Van,Name8,Email8@xyz.com
```

The problem is, the number of names and emails for one kind of housing is unknown.

I generated three lists:

```
Housing:      
House
Flat
Campervan 

Names:
Name1
Name2
Name3
Name4
Name5
Name6
Name7
Name8

Email:
Email1@xyz.com
Email2@xyz.com
...
Email8@xyz.com
```

But I am stuck how to repeat House and Flat and Campervan as much as there are names or emails (both always exact the same amount) for each category in Column 1. This would make all List match each other in length.

If I was able to this I could just generate the information I need.
Any help is appreciated.

ATTENTION: names and Email adress are not the same so for example Name1 is hans his email might be Peter@foo.org by numbering names and emails i did try to show  that emails and names  are kind of sorted and can not be enlistetd randomly

Comment: I assume that instead of Email8 you just have a list of emails like foo@bar.com and you want to extract these pattern right?

Comment: yes but names and emails dont match :(

Comment: According to your example data, names and emails can be mapped respectively e.g. (name1, name2) -> (email@1, email@2)

Comment: yes my bad i have to clarify this, Also i had to edit my Camper Van to show some difficulties. i did try to implement your Solution buit got stuck, so it was clear i did miss to point out a few things

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the data in a data.table (convert using `setDT()`), using data.table joins and the data.table `tstrsplit()` function:

```
library(data.table)
# Data for the demo (please provide this yourself in future questions)
dt1 <-
  data.table(type = c("House", "Flat", "Mobile", "Camper-van"),
             name = c("Name1", "Name2;Name3", "Name4", "Name5;Name6;Name7;Name8"),
             mail = c("Email1", "Email2;Email3", "Email4", "Email5;Email6;Email7;Email8"))

# solution
dt1[, c("type" = list(type), tstrsplit(name, ";"))][, melt(.SD, id.vars="type")][!is.na(value), .(.I, type, "name" = value)][
  dt1[, c("type" = list(type), tstrsplit(mail, ";"))][, melt(.SD, id.vars="type")][!is.na(value), .(.I, "mail" = value)], on="I"][, -c("I")]
```

Comment: note that this solution will fall down if names exist without email addresses and vice versa (e.g. you have name3 but no email3)

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

example_text <-"House,Name1,Email@1
Flat,Name2;Name3,Email@2;Email@3
Mobile Home,Name4,Email@4
Camper-Van,Name5;Name6;Name7;Name8,Email@5;Email@6;Email@7;Email@8
"
example_text %>%
  read_lines() %>%
  map(~ {
    # the first words until a delimiter
    house <- .x %>% str_extract("^[^;,]+")
    elements <- .x %>% str_remove(house) %>% str_split("[,;]") %>% simplify() %>% discard(~ .x == "")
    # Everything with an @ symbol betwwen two demiliters (, or ;)
    Emails <- elements %>% keep(~ .x %>% str_detect("@"))
    # Everything which is not one of the above
    Names <- elements %>% setdiff(Emails)
    
    tibble(
      House = house,
      Emails = Emails,
      Names = Names
    )
  }) %>%
  reduce(bind_rows)
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>   House       Emails  Names
#>   <chr>       <chr>   <chr>
#> 1 House       Email@1 Name1
#> 2 Flat        Email@2 Name2
#> 3 Flat        Email@3 Name3
#> 4 Mobile Home Email@4 Name4
#> 5 Camper-Van  Email@5 Name5
#> 6 Camper-Van  Email@6 Name6
#> 7 Camper-Van  Email@7 Name7
#> 8 Camper-Van  Email@8 Name8
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: i will give it a try thanks man